# Estilo navegacion del header

Tags: html, css

Tengo este error, y es que vivienda pasiva no consigo ponerlo en una linea, me sale siempre separado, el casa es que ni dandole width ni nada consigo arregrarlo, ¿alguna sugerencia?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CSS**

```
.menu {
        position: relative;
        width: 70%;
        height: auto;
        transform: translateX(0%);
        float: right;
        display: table;
        top: 22px;
    }

    .menu a {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: rgb(227, 30, 36);
        font-size: 12px;
        border: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        background-color: #fff;
        transition: .5s;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .menu a.active,
    .menu a:hover{
        color: #fff;
        background: rgb(227, 30, 36);
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <a href="./index.php"><div class="logo"></div></a>
        <input type="checkbox" id="menu-bar">
        <label id="etiqueta-menu" onclick="javascript:changeClass();" class="fas fa-bars" for="menu-bar"></label>
                <nav id="nav" class="menu">
                    <a href="index.php?option=inmobiliaria">Inmobiliaria</a>
                    <a href="index.php?option=constructora">Constructora</a>
                    <a href="index.php?option=viviendapasiva">Vivienda Pasiva</a>
                    <a href="index.php?option=eficiencia">Eficiencia</a>
                    <a href="index.php?option=montes">Montes</a>
                    <a href="index.php?option=seguros">Seguros</a>
                    <a href="index.php?option=contacto">Contacto</a>
                </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="social-bar">
    <a href="" class="icon icon-facebook" target="_blank"></a>
    <a href="#" class="icon icon-envelop" target="_blank"></a>
    <a href="#" class="icon icon-whatsapp" target="_blank"></a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Así a simple vista si en el css le pones a la clase `menu` el `width: auto` en lugar de poner **70%** debería ponerse en una línea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Añade la propiedad `white-space: nowrap;` dentro de `.menu a` y fuerzas a que salga siempre en una linea, otra cosa es que te quepa...

Comment: ya me lo habia comentado otro compañero y me cabe sin problema!!

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es muy simple:

Tienes un `<nav id="nav" class="menu">` que va a ocupar siempre el 70% de la pantalla. Por lo que todo lo que esté en su interior va a ser de tamaño dinámico!

El menú fisicamente por el texto ocupa un espacio minimo y para pantallas grandes se va redireccionando, ahora al intentar reducir el espacio cuando la pantalla (ventana de navegador) es mas pequeña de lo esperado, la palabra compuesta "Vivienda Pasiva" se divide dinámicamente en un intento de cumplir con tu condición del 70% de la pantalla. Para solucionarlo  tienes una propiedad white-space: nowrap; que evita esta situación y que puede añadir a .menu.

Si no quieres quitar esta condición previa, solo tienes que añadirle un decorador indicando que esta palabra compuesta no se gestione dinámicamente su tamaño:

```
<div style="width: 105px;">
    <a href="index.php?option=viviendapasiva">Vivienda Pasiva</a>
</div>
```

[Aquí te dejo un ejemplo para que lo pruebes.](https://jsfiddle.net/1jd9n68a/8/)

Comment: también correcto! mil gracias compañero!

Answer (score 1):

añade la propiedad white-space: nowrap; dentro de .menu a y fuerzas a que salga siempre en una linea,

Comment: mil gracias!!! Funciona a la pefección!!